# Sending data at the same time as connecting using sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets, client

Using sockets in java, is it possible to send information at the same time as connecting?

For example I want a remote device to control another device (such as a virtual appliance) using 'Client Server'. So the remote will switch the appliance on. When I connect to the Server I would like to allow the server to be able to determine what type of device it is, either a remote or appliance without sending a messages after connecting.

Is this possible? Or would there be a better way to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by sending information at the same time as connecting?  During the TCP handshake? That's not possible.  Why do you think you need to do this, as opposed to having the client just send the first packet to identify itself after connection?

Comment: I am just trying to explore different ways and I wasn't sure if you could attach some sort of identification message using sockets or datagram sockets. I know that during the three way handshake you can not do this.

Comment: Once the handshake is done you're connected. Either side can send at that point, and it's up to your higher-level protocol to manage that.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up different ports on the server, and have different kinds of devices connect to different ports. That way, the port number of the incoming connection would identify the device before the first byte of payload data has been transferred.